# clicked() signal for QListView in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlistview

I have a working QListView, but from the documentation, I can't figure out how to get a signal to fire with the index of the newly selected item. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually I'm having the same issue... I can't get a clicked(item) event to fire at all!

Answer (score 1):

Imho, an easier way to achieve this would be to use a QListWidget instead of a QListView, this way you could use the itemClicked signal, which sends the selected item to the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

These is a snipplet of code of how I achieved it:

```
class VenueList(QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent, venues):
        super(VenueList, self).__init__(parent)
        self.clicked.connect(self.venue_selected)
        [...]

    def venue_selected(self, index):
        venue = self.model().data(index, VenueListModel.VenueRole)
        doStuff()
```

You can browse the full code of how I used this [here](https://github.com/hobarrera/UberSquare/blob/master/ubersquare/venues.py) (line 69).  I do warn you, however, that this code is pretty bad, and needs some serious refactoring.